# EmployeeFilterSet resolved field 'emp_photo' with 'exact' lookup to an unrecognized field type ImageField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-filter

I am trying to set up django filter but keep seeing an error message as shown below

> EmployeeFilterSet resolved field 'emp_photo' with 'exact' lookup to an unrecognized field type ImageField. Try adding an override to 'Meta.filter_overrides'. See: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filterset.html#customise-filter-generation-with-filter-overrides

To the best of my knowledge, I followed the docs [as seen here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#overriding-default-filters).

My models:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import django_filters
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Employee(models.Model):
    # basic information of employee
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=40)
    emp_photo = models.ImageField(_('passport'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(_('birthday'))
    gender = models.CharField(_('gender'), max_length=15, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=['MALE', 'Male'])
    house_address = models.CharField(_('house address'), max_length=50)
    city_of_residence = models.CharField(_('city'), max_length=40)
    state_of_residence = models.CharField(_('state'), max_length=40, choices=NIGERIAN_STATE_CHOICES)
    country_of_residence = models.CharField(_('country'), max_length=40, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES,
                                            default=[156, 'Nigeria'])
    state_of_origin = models.CharField(_('state of origin'), max_length=40, choices=NIGERIAN_STATE_CHOICES)
    local_govt_of_origin = models.CharField(_('LGA of origin'), max_length=40)
    town_or_city_of_origin = models.CharField(_('town or city'), max_length=40)
    nationality = models.CharField(_('nationality'), max_length=40, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, default=[156, 'Nigeria'])
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"))
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                                 message="phone number must be entered in the "
                                         "format: '+2340000000000'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(_('phone number'), validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)

   # employment record of employee
    emp_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True, default=1)
    job_title = models.CharField(_('job title'), max_length=50)
    dept_name = models.CharField(_('department name'), max_length=50)
    branch_name = models.CharField(_('branch name'), max_length=50)
    hire_date = models.DateField(_('hire date'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Employee')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Employees')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

class EmployeeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(method='custom_filter')

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = ['emp_photo']
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'branch_name']

    def custom_filter(self, queryset, value, first_name=None):
        return queryset.filter(**{
            first_name: value,
        })
```

Tables:

```
import django_tables2 as tables

from .models import Employee

class EmployeeTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap-responsive.html"
        fields = ("emp_id", "first_name", "last_name", "job_title", "dept_name", "hire_date")
        export_formats = ['csv', 'xlsx']
```

Views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from django_tables2.export import TableExport

from .models import Employee
from .models import EmployeeFilter
from .tables import EmployeeTable


@login_required()
def employees(request):
    filter = EmployeeFilter(request.GET, queryset=Employee.objects.all())
    table = EmployeeTable(filter.qs)
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

    export_format = request.GET.get("_export", None)

    if TableExport.is_valid_format(export_format):
        exporter = TableExport(export_format, table)
        return exporter.response("table.{}".format("csv", "xlsx"))

    return render(request, "employees/employees.html", {
        "table": table,
        "filter": filter
    })
```

Template:

```
 <!--Employees data-->
            <div class="filter-container container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <!--filter form-->
                        <form action="" class="form form-inline employee-search-form" method="get">
                            {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}
                            {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="btn-group download-btn">
                            <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"
                                    class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
                                Download
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% querystring '_export'='csv' %}">csv</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% querystring '_export'='xlsx' %}">xlsx</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- data rendered here -->
            {% render_table table 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html' %}
        </div>
```

Error message:
[image: error image]

I will very much appreciate if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

django-filter does not support `ImageField` as you can see [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#filters). You do need to add only fields with supported types to the filter set.

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from django_tables2.export import TableExport

from .models import Employee
from .filters import EmployeeFilter
from .tables import EmployeeTable


@login_required()
def employees(request):
    filter = EmployeeFilter(request.GET, queryset=Employee.objects.all())
    table = EmployeeTable(filter.qs) # You needed to associate filter to table to make it work.
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

    export_format = request.GET.get("_export", None)

    if TableExport.is_valid_format(export_format):
        exporter = TableExport(export_format, table)
        return exporter.response("table.{}".format("csv", "xlsx"))

    return render(request, "employees/employees.html", {
        "table": table,
        "filter": filter
    })
```

**employees.html**

```html
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Books</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <!--Employees data-->
             <div class="filter-container container-fluid">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-10">
                         <!--filter form-->
                         <form action="" class="form form-inline employee-search-form" method="get">
                             {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}
                             {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
                         </form>
                     </div>

                     <div class="col-md-2">
                         <div class="btn-group download-btn">
                             <button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"
                                     class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle"
                                     data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
                                 Download
                             </button>
                             <div class="dropdown-menu">

                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <!-- data rendered here -->
             {% render_table table 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html' %}
         </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**EmployeeFilter**

```
#I've changed this class to make it simple.
class EmployeeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ["emp_id", "first_name", "last_name", "job_title", "dept_name", "hire_date"]
```

P.S. There are some fields on your FilterSet aren't declared within your model. I think you just forgot to edit it.

Comment: Thank you for helping out, it worked. But one last thing, I realised that when I tried to filter, all data in the table disappears even though the search queryset exist in the db. For instance, I tried searching using first and last names but instead of showing me the query result, it brought out the table heading only.

Comment: Hi, @phagyrhe. I've edited the answer including template example.

Comment: I tried this as well, qs result was showing no data, however the table is rendering the data as usual. Just that anytime I use the filter, no result is shown.

Comment: Ok, could you please provide the code of your template and `EmployeeTable`?@phagyrhe

Comment: Are you trying the exact `first_name`? Here it's working just fine.@phagyrhe

Comment: Hello @Eliakin. I made some corrections to the codes, you can check them out. As stated earlier, despite all these, the filter results are not showing, although the filter form is showing, if I initiate a search, an empty table will be shown.

Comment: Thanks. I will be expecting.

Comment: @phagyrhe could you please provide your `EmployeeFilter` class?

Comment: Hi, @phagyrhe. I've just fixed it to you. I hope it works to you :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have edited the model code to add the fields I missed out. I tried out all that you outlined, unfortunately I got this error message **"type object 'filter' has no attribute 'qs'"** in my template. When I checked my views, I realised that 'qs' is highlighted. How can I have this resolved?

Comment: which django-filter version are you using?@phagyrhe

Comment: Here it's working fine. I am using `django-filter==2.2.0` and
`django-tables2==2.2.1`.

Comment: Please show me your views.py as it's after the changes.@phagyrhe

Comment: @Eliakin...I had to go over my codes one by one to see where I erred. I realised I did not delete the custom query function in my models. After doing that, everything got fixed, thanks to you! You save me a whole lot of headache. This aside, I realised that the search query is case sensitive. For instance, when I searched for a table data with a first name that starts with uppercase "S", it brought out a search result due to the fact that this is how the data was saved. However, when I searched for the same query using lowercase "s", nothing was shown, is there a way around this?

Comment: @Eliakin...my views have also been modified to let you see how it is after effecting the corrections.

Comment: @phagyrhe `first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')` within your filter class.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept this answer, as your initial problem was solved. If you have any other questions, you have to ask a new one :) @phagyrhe